# How to stop creation of a window in OnCreate method in mfc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, activex

I have an active x control in MFC. When we create a new window for that active x control the method OnCreate() is called for this active x control. In the OnCreate method a DLL is loaded.
I want to stop creation of the window if the loading of DLL fails. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the return value.

> 0 to continue with the frame creation; -1 to destroy the frame.

Comment: the application crashes after i change the value to -1